# Deploying Redmine on Cloud Foundry: libmysqlclient.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, redmine, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to push a Redmine 2.3.0 versión and I'm getting the following error.

```
Running rake assets:precompile
[2013-04-16 23:37:08] Assets precompilation failed: rake aborted!
[2013-04-16 23:37:08] libmysqlclient.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - 
/var/vcap/data/stager/tmp/d20130416-26326-n1cta5/rubygems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so

.......

[2013-04-01 07:38:32] (See full trace by running task with --trace)[23-04-01 07:38:32] Turning on live assets compilation
[2013-04-01 07:38:32] Creating droplet
[2013-04-01 07:38:34] Uploading droplet
[2013-04-01 07:38:36] Done!

The error messages from the console, it says failed to start instances.

Uploading redmine_... O
Stopping redmine_... OK

Starting redmine_... OK
Checking redmine_...
0/1 instances: 1 starting
0/1 instances: 1 down
0/1 instances: 1 down
0/1 instances: 1 down
0/1 instances: 1 down
0/1 instances: 1 down
```

Any one know the reason?

I'm working with a Mac OSX Snow Leopard, Redmine 2.3.0, ruby 1.9.2p320 and Rails 3.2.13

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem according to http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2013/01/10/cloud-foundry-now-supports-rails-assets-pipeline/ 
   Run this:

```
    RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```